# MS SQL Server 2008 shows value passed to stored procedure but VB.NET says it isn't

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, parameters

Simple scenario: through VB.NET I'm calling a stored procedure like this:

```
Public Shared Function NameToCallStoredProcedure(ByVal Interkey As Integer) As DataSet
        Dim db As Database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase()        
        Dim sqlCommand As String = "dbo.myStoredProcedureName"
        Dim DbCommandObject As DbCommand = db.GetSqlStringCommand(sqlCommand)
        db.AddInParameter(DbCommandObject, "InterKey", DbType.Int64, Interkey)
        Return db.ExecuteDataSet(DbCommandObject)
End Function
```

Here is the entire stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoredProcedureName]
    @InterKey INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Err INT

    SELECT 
        mfg.FuncID, 
        mi.SenderID, mi.ReceiverID, 
        mfg.GroupKey,
        mi.InterDate, mi.ControlNo, mi.InterTime 
    FROM 
        table1 mfg, table2 mi 
    WHERE 
        mfg.Interkey = mi.Interkey 
        AND mfg.Interkey = @InterKey

    SET @Err = @@Error

    RETURN @Err
END
```

When my VB code calls the stored procedure I get an error that says:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Procedure or function 'myStoredProcedure' expects parameter '@InterKey', which was not supplied.'

I've triple checked that the names of the variable are right. I've used the SQL Server Profiler and it even says that when the stored procedure is called that a variable named "InterKey" is passed with a value of 1. I'm at my wits end. PLEASE someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try with `db.AddInParameter(DbCommandObject, "@InterKey", DbType.Int64, Interkey)`

Comment: sorry, didn't understand at first, I'll give that a try

Comment: You have it without the `@`

Comment: You also should start using ANSI-92 style joins, they have been available for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: @Sean Lange - thanks for the suggestion, but that has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: @BrendonDavies I hope your `Dim DbCommandObject As DbCommand = db.GetSqlStringCommand(sqlCommand)`  is the same as the `System.Data.Common.DbCommand` as setting the Command Type to `CommandType.StoredProcedure` should see you set right

Comment: It does actually have something to do with your question, it just isn't part of the solution. ;) Simply add a line DbCommandObject.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure before you execute it and it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code

```
db.AddInParameter(DbCommandObject, "InterKey", DbType.Int64, Interkey)
```

First, try "@InterKey" instead of "InterKey"
Second, I think INT in SQL Server is Int32 in .Net. Your DbType could cause a narrowing conversion which is not allowed by the server.

Comment: I tried both suggestions, sadly neither worked. Thanks a lot for the suggestions.

Comment: If you can get hold of the connection string, I would try it the old fashion way. Plain old ADO.net, no factories. If that works then that narrows the problem to a factory class.

Answer (score 0):

A co-worker helped me figure out what the problem was. In the calling of my stored procedure I had `db.GetSqlStringCommand` and it should have been `db.GetStoredProcCommand`. Thanks to everyone that offered help.